# access an array at a specific index

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexing, methods

I am trying to create an array then fill that array only at certain indexes. Can I append the array contents with user input? How to display it to an another method? Here is my code that I can't solve it.

```
public class data{

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] name = new String[99];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        user();
        for(int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
            System.out.println(name[i]);
        }
    }

    static void user(){
        name[0] = "Syifa ";
        System.out.println("Name:" +name[0]);
        for(int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Name: ");
            name[] = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use indentation and white space to make your code easier to read.

Comment: The line `name[] = sc.nextLine();` wont work, you need to specify the index at which you want to write to: `name[i] = sc.nextLine();`. Also the iteration should probably start from index 1 since you are already setting index 0 to "Syifa".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have created the method, `user`, just create another method (e.g. `display` as shown below) inside which you can iterate the array and display the names.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int SIZE = 5;// Change the value as per your requirement
    static String[] name = new String[SIZE];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        user();
        display();
    }

    static void user() {
        name[0] = "Syifa ";
        System.out.println("Name:" + name[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < name.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Next name: ");
            name[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }

    static void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(name[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Name:Syifa 
Next name: Hello
Next name: Merry
Next name: Christma
Next name: World
Syifa 
Hello
Merry
Christma
World
```

**Note:** since you have already stored a name at `name[0]`, you should start the loop inside the method, `user` with `i = 1`. Also, you need to assign the input to `name[i]` instead of `name[]`.